# How can I achieve this low contrast effect in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop

Using Camera Raw or Photoshop, how can I achieve this look?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/adriellyalves/9854934404/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/adriellyalves/9764912546/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/adriellyalves/9702438911/

Comment: What do you think the effect is? http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply low contrast images.  Drop the contrast down, possibly pull in the white and black points so that they are grey rather than white and black as well.

Comment: Though personally, I don't think any of those samples are particularly well done, so I'd generally try to avoid that look unless there was a particular shot that called for it.

Answer (score 2):

The images you linked to are low contrast with elevated exposure.

To get this look:

- Reduce the overall contrast
- Reduce the highlights and brighten the shadows
- Increase overall brightness/exposure a little to the right of zero

But why would you want to?